A sequence about sums of prime numbers.
I was playing with primes lately and thought about terms of a possible sequence.

Let's define $p_n$ as the $n$th prime number from the smallest prime number.
A sum of prime numbers from 1st to the $n$th prime number can be expressed as $$\sum_{k=1}^n p_k$$
This is the smallest possible sum of $n$ different primes. For an even $n$, this is the smallest sum of $n$ different primes which is odd. For an odd $n$ on the other hand, the sum is even, so the smallest sum of $n$ different primes which is odd can be expressed as
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} p_k = \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} p_k - 2$$
The smallest sum of $n$ primes that is odd can be expressed as
$$S_n =
\begin{cases}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} p_k, & \text{if $n$ is even, $n \ge 2$} \\\\[2ex]
\sum_{k=2}^{n+1} p_k, & \text{if $n$ is odd, $n \ge 2$} 
\end{cases}
$$
Now, we can check the primality of $S_n$ for all natural number $n$.
For example, $S_4$ is a prime where, $$S_4 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17$$
and $S_3$ isn't where $$S_3 = 3 + 5 + 7 = 15$$
Let's define a sequence $a_m$ about a primality of $S_n$. $m \left(m \ge 2\right)$ is a size of an interval $ \left\{ b_1, b_2, \dots ,b_m \right\} \subset \mathbb N $.
$a_m$ is the smallest $n$ where $S_n$ is a prime for every natural number in an interval with a size of $m$.
For instance, $a_2 = 14$ where, $S_{14}, S_{15}$ each is a prime and it's the first occurrence where 2 consecutive $S_n$ is a prime. There are more terms of the sequence.
$$
\begin{align}
& a_3 = 1117 \\\\
& a_4 = 1190 \\\\
& a_5 = 126333 \\\\
\end{align}
$$
I wrote a program in C calculating these things and happened to get some terms but I still couldn't get the 5th term of the sequence, $a_6$.
Up to $n = 33400000$, there was no such $a_6$.
Finally, I found that there should be infinitely many twin primes for $a_m$ to be defined for every $m$.
$$
\begin{align}
& S_2 = 2 + 3 \\\\
& S_3 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 - 2 \\\\
& S_4 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 \\\\
& S_5 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 - 2 \\\\
& S_6 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 \\\\
& . \\\\
& . \\\\
& .
\end{align}
$$
As you can see, $S_3, S_4$ and $S_5, S_6$ differ by 2. This means that there should be at least 2 pairs of twin primes for $a_6$ to exist. Also, the gap between those twin primes should be a sum of 2 specific consecutive primes.
I can't imagine how large a term can be, let alone not sure if terms even exist.
I want to know if there's any relevant research about this sequence or the idea.

The sequence of the sums of the first $n$ primes  is A007504

Thanks for the comment! Sadly, I've already searched about that sequence.

Are you looking for $6$ consecutive members of the prime-sum sequence that are all prime ?

Concerning the twin prime : We do not even know whether there are infinite many twin primes at all , but nevertheless this sequence might contain infinite many of them.

$a_2=1$ as $S_1=3$ and $S_2 = 5$

Yes you're right. I am finding the 5th term of this sequence. Also, I am aware of twin prime conjecture but is there any same research about this?

Yes, $a_2 = 1$ if we count $n=1$ for $S_n$. So, $a_1 = 1$ and $a_2 = 1$ where $n \in \mathbb N$.

If you drop odd $n$, your question becomes if there are arbitrary long segments in A013916 with difference $2$. And I think it's not even known if the sequence is infinite.

The first sequence of $6$ times in a row ends with $k=48\ 475\ 156$ Please check !

Wow, It sure is. $S_n$ is prime 6 times in a row where $k= 48475156$ is the end. I don't know if it is the first occurrence of it. How did you find it? I can't think of better idea finding this.

A013916 can be bit easier to deal with I guess? So that I can cut out every non-candidates for $a_m$.

@mokrodo923 A cleverly written PARI/GP routine was enough. There is  no $7$-sequence upto $1.2\cdot 10^9$. Code : d=0;k=1;s=2;p=2;while(k<10^11,k=k+1;p=nextprime(p+1);s=s+p;u=s;if(Mod(s,2)==0,u=s+nextprime(p+1)-2);if(ispseudoprime(u)==0,d=0);if(ispseudoprime(u)==1,d=d+1);if(d>=5,print(k,"  ",u,"    ",d)))

I haven't known about this great C library for computing these kind of number things until now. Code is also easily understandable. Writing the code with pure C was really hard for me as it was my first time using C so, I was wondering all day how you got the result so fast. . You totally saved my day sir! Thanks for all the efforts!

No $7$-sequence upto $3.7\cdot 10^9$

Are you using the code above or optimized it? I slightly modified it. Here's the code. d=0;
k=1;
s=2;
p=2;
whole(a) =
{
while(k<a,
k=k+1;
p=nextprime(p+1);
s=s+p);
}
test(b,m) =
{
while(k<b,
k=k+1;
p=nextprime(p+1);
s=s+p;
u=s;
if(Mod(s,2)==0,
u=s+nextprime(p+1)-2);
if(ispseudoprime(u)==0,
d=0);
if(ispseudoprime(u)==1,
d=d+1);
if(d==m,
print("Where occurrence start: ",k-m+1," The sum of last part: ",u," m is ",d)));
}

You can memo k, p, s and use it whenever you want using "test" function without re-calculating a sum of primes from the scratch. It's fine if you got better process finding the sequence but just in case.

I arrived at $7.6\cdot 10^9$. I think it is quite "bad luck" that there is still no $7$-sequence.

Problem of this process is that it's linear. If you got your computer doing this job for as long as you can run, it'll be fine but if isn't, you can let me know the value of k, p, s so I can keep it up with you.

I think , I have finally found a $7$-sequence ending at $k=9\ 980\ 662\ 273$. The corresponding sum should be $1229509249423185858821$

Wow, you found a promising one.

A doublecheck of this result is very appreciated !

Nice! How far have you gone through? I computed it until k=105*10^8 thanks to your reply. Maybe, 8-sequence will be far far away from here.

NO 8-sequence found until $k=11.1⋅10^9$.

For now, $a_{n+1}/a{n}$ is roughly around $80$ to $300$ except for n=2. I hope the term will exist close to $k=10⋅10^11$.

I have given up the search. Good luck to find the 8-sequence. Have you doublechecked my result ?

Yes, I have verified the result and it is a real 7-sequence. Thanks for all the efforts you put on this.
